# Laravel 8 and Vue Js page vue template not displaying

Tags: vue.js, laravel-8

I installed a fresh Laravel 8 and Vue js. Upon installing the `npm` and `Vue`, it installs well. Now my problem is when I run the `npm run watch` then load, the page is blank, it seems `Vue` is not loading.

My `testapp.vue`:

```html
<template>
    <div>
        <h1>Hello world! asasasaas</h1>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        mounted() {
            console.log('Component mounted.')
        }
    }
</script>
```

My `views/testpage.blade.php`:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Testpage</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="app">
       <main-app></main-app>
    </div>
</body>
 <script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}"></script>
</html>
```

My `js/app.js`:

```js
require('./bootstrap');

window.Vue = require('vue');

Vue.component('main-app', require('./components/TestApp.vue').default);

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app'
});
```

My `webpack.mix.js`:

```js
const mix = require('laravel-mix');

/*
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 | Mix Asset Management
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 |
 | Mix provides a clean, fluent API for defining some Webpack build steps
 | for your Laravel applications. By default, we are compiling the CSS
 | file for the application as well as bundling up all the JS files.
 |
 */

mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
   .postCss('resources/css/app.css', 'public/css', [
      // require('postcss-import'),
      //  require('tailwindcss'),
      //  require('autoprefixer'),
   ])
   .vue();
```

My `route/web.php`:

```
Route::get('/test', [TestController::class, 'index']);
```

Can someone help me figured this thing out?

Comment: I am not sure what browser are you using, but try opening it `devs tools`, if you are using `chrome`, press `F12` or right click anywhere in the blank page and then click on `console` tab in the new window. Show us if you have any error there.